# Is there CRF available in NvEnc (Nvidia Video Codec SDK 7.1.9)?

Tags: h.264, h.265, nvenc

I'm unable to find any mention of CRF in the NvEnc documentation and the Nvidia developer forum. There are quite a few speculations to be found online, in relation with ffmpeg (as in "doesn't *seem* to be supported"), but nothing really definite nor up-to-date. Can anybody shed some light on this? In case it really isn't supported, is there a technical reason or will it be added in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**crf** (constant rate factor) is a video quality setting that only exists in x264 and x265. It is not part of the HEVC standard, so don't expect to find it in any other HEVC encoder.

Comment: Are you sure about your answer? HEVC is x265 .And NVENC supports both x264 and x265 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding

Comment: it's the other way round: x265 is HEVC. There are other HEVC encoders that won't have CRF because it's not part of the standard.